# More efficient way of serialization and deserialization?

Tags: c#, json

I have the below classes.

```
public class Source { public string ConfigData { get; set; } }
public class Configuration { public IEnumerable<IpAddress> IpAddresses { get; set; } }

public class IpAddress
{
    
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public Family IPFamily { get; set; }
}
```

First, I am getting the ConfigData  as string from a source and deserializing it below:

```
var storedIPAddresses =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>( source.ConfigData).IpAddresses;
```

Next I am doing some checks, which essentially sets the values of IsValid and IPFamily.

```
if (storedIPAddresses.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var ipDetail in storedIPAddresses)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipDetail.StartIpAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipDetail.EndIpAddress))
                        {
                            if (bla == blabla)
                            {
                                ipDetail.IsValid = true;
                                ipDetail.IPFamily = IPAddressFamily.IPV4;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Lastly, I am supposed to return the souce object by chucking in the updated storedIPAddresses inside, which is where I need some guidance.
I am able to do in following way; but looking for any more elegant way?

```
var config = new Configuration();
config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(source.ConfigData);
config.IpAddresses = storedIPAddresses;
source.ConfigData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);
return source;
```

Comment: What you have is fine all things considered, you will be fighting a losing battle getting this more efficient or explicit and readable (given your criteria)... You should likely work on bigger problems

Comment: You can manipulate Json directly if you want. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/modifyjson.htm

Comment: @Klamsi that is very unlikely to be more efficient :/

Comment: @TheGeneral: You get rid of reflection things. But I agree, I would not expect a performance boost.

Comment: What is your key measurement for "efficiency"? You _may_ get something out of memory / execution time by switching to another JSON lib like System.Text.Json (but always run your horses!).

Comment: @Fildor Ahh yes this is newtonsoft. text.json for the win

Comment: ^^ Newtonsoft is cool and has many features other libs do not have, **but** that's exactly what is was designed for: features over efficient implementations. So, if you don't need one of the features the other libs don't have, it _may_ be worthwhile to run some benchmarks comparing newtonsoft to for example text.json

Comment: Thanks Guys, I was looking for some ways to fiddle the JSON object in-place rather than serialize and deserialize, but I understand, that's something not worth in here given the readability and maintainability?

Comment: If you didn't measture that this code gives you perfomance bottleneck - then don't bother.

Comment: Nah. Don't. That will soon be a maintainance hell. Deserialize, Alter, Serialize. That's readable _and_ robust. If you want to improve on speed / memory footprint, consider more efficient libs. But even that: I'd only consider _if_ any of speed / throughput / memory becomes an actual issue.

Comment: Plug in you data class to: https://github.com/Alois-xx/SerializerTests and let it run on ca. 20 serialization libraries. Pick then the best one. Some libs use binary format which might be more efficient.